# How can I make angles not act weird?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, sfml, angle

I'm new to programming and SFML. I'm trying to make something like a canon. It's gonna fire balls that will be flying in an arc. Sounds like a very simple task to accomplish, yet I cannot seem to figure out how angles work in SFML. For example, with ang_const = 0.13 Rad (7.44 Deg), my balls flies in a beautiful arc. However, when I change the value of ang_const to 0.14 Rad (8.021 Deg), the ball flies in the opposite direction! If I change the angle to 0.19 Rad (10.88 Deg), it flies downwards for whatever reason.

So here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <math.h>
int WIDTH = 1024, HEIGHT = 704;

class Ball {
private:
float radius = 16.00;
public:
sf::CircleShape shape;
Ball () {
    shape.setPosition(0 + radius*2, HEIGHT - radius*2);
    shape.setRadius(radius);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
    shape.setOrigin(radius, radius);
}
void update() {
    if (x() - radius > WIDTH) {
        this->shape.setPosition(0 - radius, y());
    }
    if (x() + radius < 0) {
        this->shape.setPosition(WIDTH + radius, y());
    }
    if (y() - radius > HEIGHT) {
        this->shape.setPosition(x(), 0 - radius);
    }
    if (y() + radius < 0) {
        this->shape.setPosition(x(), HEIGHT + radius);
    }
}
float RadToDeg (float radian) {
    double pi = 3.14159;
    return radian * (180 / pi);
}
float x() { return shape.getPosition().x; }
float y() { return shape.getPosition().y; }
float getRadius() { return radius; }
};

int main()
{
// Create the main window
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "del");

// Some variables
float ang_const = 0.13;                   
float velX_const = 3.5, velY_const = 3.5; 
float grav_const = -0.02;                

float ang = ang_const;
float velX = velX_const, velY = velY_const;
float grav = grav_const;

// Text
int size_for_text = 64;
sf::Font f;
f.loadFromFile("Keyboard.ttf");
sf::Text text1;
text1.setFont(f);
text1.setCharacterSize(27);
text1.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
text1.setPosition(size_for_text, size_for_text);

// Ball
Ball ball;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window: exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }

        // Escape pressed: exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
            window.close();
        }

        // Restart
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) {
            ang = ang_const;
            velX = velX_const, velY = velY_const;
            grav = grav_const;
            ball.shape.setPosition(0 + ball.getRadius()*2, HEIGHT - ball.getRadius()*2);
        }
    }

    // Ball movement
    ball.update();

    velY += grav;
    ball.shape.move(velX * cos(ball.RadToDeg(ang)),
                    velY * -sin(ball.RadToDeg(ang)));

    // Clear screen
    window.clear(sf::Color(0,0,80,100));

    // Draw ball
    window.draw(ball.shape);

    // Draw text
    text1.setString("ang " + std::to_string(ang));
    window.draw(text1);

    // Update the window
    window.display();
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The main lines are these:
Variables:

```
float ang_const = 0.13;                 
float velX_const = 3.5, velY_const = 3.5;
float grav_const = -0.02;
```

Ball movement:

```
velY += grav;
ball.shape.move(velX * cos(ball.RadToDeg(ang)), velY * - 
sin(ball.RadToDeg(ang)));
```

Radians to Degrees function:

```
float RadToDeg (float radian) {
double pi = 3.14159;
return radian * (180 / pi);
}
```

Could someone explain what's wrong with my code and how angles work in SFML? I'd be appreciated for your help guys.

Comment: `cos()` and `sin()` take argument in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the trigonometric functions defined in `<cmath>` expect their parameters to be values representing angles in **radians** (see e.g. [std::cos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cos)).

So, when you write something like

```
cos(ball.RadToDeg(ang))
```

where `ang` is equal to, say 0.13, `RadToDeg` will convert it to 7.44, but, even if your intention is to pass an angle in degrees, that value is interpreted by `std::cos` (and `std::sin`) as an angle of 7.44 *radians* (or 66.28°).

That leads to your unexpected results:

cos<sub>r</sub>(7.44) = **0.505**  (instead of  cos<sub>d</sub>(7.44°) = 0.993) and
cos<sub>r</sub>(8.021) = **-0.166**  (instead of  cos<sub>d</sub>(8.021°) = 0.992)